# Rational Numbers and Finite sets

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, rational-numbers

Let $q$ be an irrational number and fix a positive integer $N$. Consider a small finite interval $(a,b)$ around $q$. Let $U$ be the set of rational numbers of the form $m/n$ such that $gcd(m,n)=1$,$n<N$ and $a<m/n<b$. Show that $U$ is finite.

I know that I must show that there is a bijection from ${1,2,...,m}$ to $U$ but I do not know how to approach this problem.

Comment: What is $m$ in your last paragraph?

Answer (score 1):

Hint. Draw a number line on which you mark all the fractions in the unit interval that satisfy the condition when, say $N=6$. Then think about the general case.

You don't need a bijection to prove the set is finite - just an argument saying there can't be more than ...

I think $q$ is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

The proposition is false.  Consider the rationals of the form $1/n$ where $n$ is allowed to be any negative integer.

Comment: Technically correct, of course - but I suspect the OP wants positive $N$. If not, he or she was asked a question with a trick answer.

Comment: It is either a typo by the OP or a blunder by the original source of the question.  I suspect the former, so the OP will probably be along soon to edit the question....